# How to add integers to char in Oracle 11g SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Is it possible to do something like this in a PL/SQL block:

`SELECT 'a'+1 FROM dual;`

and the result should be "b".

Comment: That will only happen in certain (very popular) character sets. A counter example is EBCDIC where `chr(ascii('i') + 1)` is not going to be `'j'`. _[U]nlike ASCII the EBCDIC alphabet is non-contiguous, interleaved with unassigned characters which may or may not be in use._ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#History

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
SELECT CHR(ASCII('a') + 1) FROM dual
```

but I bet there is something more tricky